# Display buttons in-line to above/ below each other using?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got the following _underscore / html line of code. It displays a button correctly.

```
wrapper.append('<div type="button" class="wrapper portfolio-item-thumb one-third btn btn-success mrs accepted">' + 'Accept' + '</div>');
```

I then have this line for another button, I want to combine the two lines of code, so that I can have both buttons in the same div and style with css `display-inline` so they appear side by side and not above/below each other.

No matter what I do I can't combine the two lines of code, can some one show me how to do this?

```
wrapper.append('<div type="button" class="wrapper portfolio-item-thumb one-third btn btn-danger mrs decline">' + 'Decline' + '</div>'+ '<br><br><br>');
```

Comment: That looked more like jQuery code than Underscore so I changed your tags.

Comment: @muistooshort ok thks

Comment: What should the final HTML look like?